# VHDL: Using type on ports

Tags: vhdl

Is it poosible to use user-defined typed in input/output of VHDL enitities?

```
ENTITY test IS
   PORT( 
      input         : IN     std_logic_vector (0 TO 63);
      test_input:   out MY_TYPE;
   );


END test ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, declare the type in a package, and use the package before the entity, and also in the modules that instantiates the module, so the same user defined type is available.

Comment: can you bring a sample code please?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872950/can-custom-types-be-used-in-port-declaration